# Best practice for binding hundreds of form fields to columns in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ajax

My team is trying to determine what the best practice for binding form fields to columns in one or more tables. We need this to work with minimal code maintenance when adding or removing fields. What we have come up with is using a data attribute for our fields and adding a generic string to the end of the SQL column.
For example:

```
<input type="text" id="lastname" data-obj="ColumnName_ID">
```

Our biggest concern is security but we would also like as minimal maintenance as possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: Give more information about technologies you are using. Using column name inside web-page, in any way, is not a best practice. Best practice is when your presentation layer (web) has no any knowledge about your data store (sql).

Comment: did you try ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Sounds like you're "saving yourself work" by doing lots of extra work....

Comment: Well it's a simple single page application where we are trying to just capture information from the user. Their isn't much complexity to it other than taking the information inputted and inserting a new record in our table. We currently are using a single AJAX call to send the information to our server-side method.